# Download Excel file from URL

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

**Background**

I am attempting to automate the downloading of an Excel file given a URL. I know how to do this, and realize there are many examples for how to do this using either the webbrowser or webclient control however my situation is somewhat different.

**Problem**

If I simply paste the URL into a normal browser, it will result in asking me to save / open the file like normal. When using the same URL with either the web browser or web client controls, it results in no file. I believe this is because the URL is simply a SharePoint link, that sends a request to get the file, but is not the actual file itself.

This can be done for security reasons or whatever the case is but I was wondering if anyone has ever found a way around this?

Perhaps a way to even just emulate the browser, then emulate clicking save?

The URL for the Excel file does NOT end in .xlsx, it ends in something like:

```
webclient/zhZZXYRyAaLUgD?TC_file=redirs/viewdataset
```

which is why I think the server simply processes the request and then provides the browser the file.

I am attempting to do this in VB.NET but VBA or VB answers seem like they should work as well.

**Fiddler Results**

[image]

Comment: Do you get any events on WebControl? Like DownloadFile or Navigating?

Comment: BTW: A url that doesn't end in xlsx can still return an excel file. What's important is the contenttype of the returned file.

Comment: It does have a navigated event that fires after. I realize that the url doesn't need to end in xlsx, I was just trying to make my point clear that the actual url doesn't contain the file, it is simply a server request which produces the file to download. What are your ideas with the navigated event?

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler (or similar) to watch what requests/responses occur when you open the file via the browser vs. other methods?  That may give you some clues.

Comment: Do you see a blank page on the WebBrowser control? Possibly you're getting a NewWindow event that you're canceling?

Comment: @TimWilliams I had never used Fiddler prior to just now but I did get a clue.. At the point of the download, it gives me a new host and URL. How do I put this together to get the actual file? I tried navigating to the host with the URL added onto the end but no page found unless I am going about that completely wrong

Comment: @jm. It navigates fine and brings up the dialog to save / open from the webbrowser control but I want it so the user doesn't see that, to goto a location I specify

Comment: Difficult for me to make any real suggestions without an actual URL to look at.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added a Fiddler screenshot to my question

Comment: I can't tell much from that, other than there seems to be a redirect (302) in there.

Comment: From what I see, the first connection establishes a cookie to identify the user, then it redirects to a second link which allows the file based on that cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seemed to find an easy way to solve my problem. After downloading my file within Internet Explorer, and then viewing my recent downloads, IE has an option if you right click and select "Copy Download Link".  This puts the true download URL in the clipboard and actually works using the My.computer.downloadfile method.